# Alinhar ícones e textos em botão

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de deixar os meus ícones (SVGs) e textos alinhados dentro do mesmo "container" da minha navbar utilizando flexbox, porém não estou conseguindo utilizar as regras corretas. 
O mais próximo que eu consegui está relatado no código abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
:root {
  --bg: #242526;
  --bg-accent: #484a4d;
  --text-color: #dadce1;
  --nav-size: 60px;
  --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --speed: 500ms;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  height: var(--nav-size);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}

.navbar-nav {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-logo {
  color: white;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-item {
  width: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.8);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-button {
  --button-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
  width: var(--button-size);
  height: var(--button-size);
  background-color: var(--bg-accent);
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: filter 300ms;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.nav-button svg,
.icon-right svg {
  fill: var(--text-color);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <img src="logo.png" width="180px" alt="logo" class="nav-logo">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zm-141.651-35.33c4.937-32.999-20.191-50.739-54.55-62.573l11.146-44.702-27.213-6.781-10.851 43.524c-7.154-1.783-14.502-3.464-21.803-5.13l10.929-43.81-27.198-6.781-11.153 44.686c-5.922-1.349-11.735-2.682-17.377-4.084l.031-.14-37.53-9.37-7.239 29.062s20.191 4.627 19.765 4.913c11.022 2.751 13.014 10.044 12.68 15.825l-12.696 50.925c.76.194 1.744.473 2.829.907-.907-.225-1.876-.473-2.876-.713l-17.796 71.338c-1.349 3.348-4.767 8.37-12.471 6.464.271.395-19.78-4.937-19.78-4.937l-13.51 31.147 35.414 8.827c6.588 1.651 13.045 3.379 19.4 5.006l-11.262 45.213 27.182 6.781 11.153-44.733a1038.209 1038.209 0 0 0 21.687 5.627l-11.115 44.523 27.213 6.781 11.262-45.128c46.404 8.781 81.299 5.239 95.986-36.727 11.836-33.79-.589-53.281-25.004-65.991 17.78-4.098 31.174-15.792 34.747-39.949zm-62.177 87.179c-8.41 33.79-65.308 15.523-83.755 10.943l14.944-59.899c18.446 4.603 77.6 13.717 68.811 48.956zm8.417-87.667c-7.673 30.736-55.031 15.12-70.393 11.292l13.548-54.327c15.363 3.828 64.836 10.973 56.845 43.035z"></path></svg>Administrativo</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M425.09 65.83c-39.88 0-73.28 25.73-83.66 64.33-18.16-58.06-65.5-64.33-84.95-64.33-19.78 0-66.8 6.28-85.28 64.33-10.38-38.6-43.45-64.33-83.66-64.33C38.59 65.83 0 99.72 0 143.03c0 28.96 4.18 33.27 77.17 233.48 22.37 60.57 67.77 69.35 92.74 69.35 39.23 0 70.04-19.46 85.93-53.98 15.89 34.83 46.69 54.29 85.93 54.29 24.97 0 70.36-9.1 92.74-69.67 76.55-208.65 77.5-205.58 77.5-227.2.63-48.32-36.01-83.47-86.92-83.47zm26.34 114.81l-65.57 176.44c-7.92 21.49-21.22 37.22-46.24 37.22-23.44 0-37.38-12.41-44.03-33.9l-39.28-117.42h-.95L216.08 360.4c-6.96 21.5-20.9 33.6-44.02 33.6-25.02 0-38.33-15.74-46.24-37.22L60.88 181.55c-5.38-14.83-7.92-23.91-7.92-34.5 0-16.34 15.84-29.36 38.33-29.36 18.69 0 31.99 11.8 36.11 29.05l44.03 139.82h.95l44.66-136.79c6.02-19.67 16.47-32.08 38.96-32.08s32.94 12.11 38.96 32.08l44.66 136.79h.95l44.03-139.82c4.12-17.25 17.42-29.05 36.11-29.05 22.17 0 38.33 13.32 38.33 35.71-.32 7.87-4.12 16.04-7.61 27.24z"></path></svg>Financeiro</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M425.09 65.83c-39.88 0-73.28 25.73-83.66 64.33-18.16-58.06-65.5-64.33-84.95-64.33-19.78 0-66.8 6.28-85.28 64.33-10.38-38.6-43.45-64.33-83.66-64.33C38.59 65.83 0 99.72 0 143.03c0 28.96 4.18 33.27 77.17 233.48 22.37 60.57 67.77 69.35 92.74 69.35 39.23 0 70.04-19.46 85.93-53.98 15.89 34.83 46.69 54.29 85.93 54.29 24.97 0 70.36-9.1 92.74-69.67 76.55-208.65 77.5-205.58 77.5-227.2.63-48.32-36.01-83.47-86.92-83.47zm26.34 114.81l-65.57 176.44c-7.92 21.49-21.22 37.22-46.24 37.22-23.44 0-37.38-12.41-44.03-33.9l-39.28-117.42h-.95L216.08 360.4c-6.96 21.5-20.9 33.6-44.02 33.6-25.02 0-38.33-15.74-46.24-37.22L60.88 181.55c-5.38-14.83-7.92-23.91-7.92-34.5 0-16.34 15.84-29.36 38.33-29.36 18.69 0 31.99 11.8 36.11 29.05l44.03 139.82h.95l44.66-136.79c6.02-19.67 16.47-32.08 38.96-32.08s32.94 12.11 38.96 32.08l44.66 136.79h.95l44.03-139.82c4.12-17.25 17.42-29.05 36.11-29.05 22.17 0 38.33 13.32 38.33 35.71-.32 7.87-4.12 16.04-7.61 27.24z"></path></svg>TI</a></li>  </ul>
</div>
```

Alguém consegue me auxiliar com esta sintaxe CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Os textos estavam **alinhados** só não estavam **cabendo** dentro do botão, pois os containers deles (*nav-item* e *nav-button*) eram de tamanho **FIXO**!

Troquei *width* por *min-width*, e o *border-radius* do *nav-button* para tamanho fixo também!

```css
:root {
  --bg: #242526;
  --bg-accent: #484a4d;
  --text-color: #dadce1;
  --nav-size: 60px;
  --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --speed: 500ms;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  height: var(--nav-size);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}

.navbar-nav {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-logo {
  color: white;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-item {
  min-width: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.8);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-button {
  --button-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
  min-width: var(--button-size);
  height: var(--button-size);
  background-color: var(--bg-accent);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: filter 300ms;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.nav-button svg,
.icon-right svg {
  fill: var(--text-color);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <img src="logo.png" width="180px" alt="logo" class="nav-logo">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zm-141.651-35.33c4.937-32.999-20.191-50.739-54.55-62.573l11.146-44.702-27.213-6.781-10.851 43.524c-7.154-1.783-14.502-3.464-21.803-5.13l10.929-43.81-27.198-6.781-11.153 44.686c-5.922-1.349-11.735-2.682-17.377-4.084l.031-.14-37.53-9.37-7.239 29.062s20.191 4.627 19.765 4.913c11.022 2.751 13.014 10.044 12.68 15.825l-12.696 50.925c.76.194 1.744.473 2.829.907-.907-.225-1.876-.473-2.876-.713l-17.796 71.338c-1.349 3.348-4.767 8.37-12.471 6.464.271.395-19.78-4.937-19.78-4.937l-13.51 31.147 35.414 8.827c6.588 1.651 13.045 3.379 19.4 5.006l-11.262 45.213 27.182 6.781 11.153-44.733a1038.209 1038.209 0 0 0 21.687 5.627l-11.115 44.523 27.213 6.781 11.262-45.128c46.404 8.781 81.299 5.239 95.986-36.727 11.836-33.79-.589-53.281-25.004-65.991 17.78-4.098 31.174-15.792 34.747-39.949zm-62.177 87.179c-8.41 33.79-65.308 15.523-83.755 10.943l14.944-59.899c18.446 4.603 77.6 13.717 68.811 48.956zm8.417-87.667c-7.673 30.736-55.031 15.12-70.393 11.292l13.548-54.327c15.363 3.828 64.836 10.973 56.845 43.035z"></path></svg>Administrativo</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M425.09 65.83c-39.88 0-73.28 25.73-83.66 64.33-18.16-58.06-65.5-64.33-84.95-64.33-19.78 0-66.8 6.28-85.28 64.33-10.38-38.6-43.45-64.33-83.66-64.33C38.59 65.83 0 99.72 0 143.03c0 28.96 4.18 33.27 77.17 233.48 22.37 60.57 67.77 69.35 92.74 69.35 39.23 0 70.04-19.46 85.93-53.98 15.89 34.83 46.69 54.29 85.93 54.29 24.97 0 70.36-9.1 92.74-69.67 76.55-208.65 77.5-205.58 77.5-227.2.63-48.32-36.01-83.47-86.92-83.47zm26.34 114.81l-65.57 176.44c-7.92 21.49-21.22 37.22-46.24 37.22-23.44 0-37.38-12.41-44.03-33.9l-39.28-117.42h-.95L216.08 360.4c-6.96 21.5-20.9 33.6-44.02 33.6-25.02 0-38.33-15.74-46.24-37.22L60.88 181.55c-5.38-14.83-7.92-23.91-7.92-34.5 0-16.34 15.84-29.36 38.33-29.36 18.69 0 31.99 11.8 36.11 29.05l44.03 139.82h.95l44.66-136.79c6.02-19.67 16.47-32.08 38.96-32.08s32.94 12.11 38.96 32.08l44.66 136.79h.95l44.03-139.82c4.12-17.25 17.42-29.05 36.11-29.05 22.17 0 38.33 13.32 38.33 35.71-.32 7.87-4.12 16.04-7.61 27.24z"></path></svg>Financeiro</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M425.09 65.83c-39.88 0-73.28 25.73-83.66 64.33-18.16-58.06-65.5-64.33-84.95-64.33-19.78 0-66.8 6.28-85.28 64.33-10.38-38.6-43.45-64.33-83.66-64.33C38.59 65.83 0 99.72 0 143.03c0 28.96 4.18 33.27 77.17 233.48 22.37 60.57 67.77 69.35 92.74 69.35 39.23 0 70.04-19.46 85.93-53.98 15.89 34.83 46.69 54.29 85.93 54.29 24.97 0 70.36-9.1 92.74-69.67 76.55-208.65 77.5-205.58 77.5-227.2.63-48.32-36.01-83.47-86.92-83.47zm26.34 114.81l-65.57 176.44c-7.92 21.49-21.22 37.22-46.24 37.22-23.44 0-37.38-12.41-44.03-33.9l-39.28-117.42h-.95L216.08 360.4c-6.96 21.5-20.9 33.6-44.02 33.6-25.02 0-38.33-15.74-46.24-37.22L60.88 181.55c-5.38-14.83-7.92-23.91-7.92-34.5 0-16.34 15.84-29.36 38.33-29.36 18.69 0 31.99 11.8 36.11 29.05l44.03 139.82h.95l44.66-136.79c6.02-19.67 16.47-32.08 38.96-32.08s32.94 12.11 38.96 32.08l44.66 136.79h.95l44.03-139.82c4.12-17.25 17.42-29.05 36.11-29.05 22.17 0 38.33 13.32 38.33 35.71-.32 7.87-4.12 16.04-7.61 27.24z"></path></svg>TI</a></li>  </ul>
</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: Ficou dessa maneira]

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema são os atributos `width` do `.nav-item` e `.nav-button`. Se remover, resolve.

Isso aconteceu porque você estava utilizando como base de cálculo o valor de `--nav-size: 60px`, que representa a **altura**, e não largura da barra de navegação.

Caso você queira fazer algo com relação à largura da barra de navegação, pode usar valores percentuais como no exemplo abaixo, onde `.nav-item` deve possuir a sua largura especificada em relação ao `.navbar-nav` e o `.nav-button` deve possuir sua largura em relação ao `.nav-item`:

```css
.nav-item {
  /** Aqui usamos min-width pois, dependendo do tamanho da resolução, o botão
      precisará de mais do que 20% para conseguir ser exibido corretamente **/
  min-width: 20%;
}

.nav-button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Claro que seu código precisa de mais adaptações para ficar responsivo corretamente, pois os botões ficam grudados e etc., mas o seu problema acontecia por causa disso.

```css
:root {
  --bg: #242526;
  --bg-accent: #484a4d;
  --text-color: #dadce1;
  --nav-size: 60px;
  --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --speed: 500ms;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  height: var(--nav-size);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}

.navbar-nav {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-logo {
  color: white;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-button {
  --button-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
  height: var(--button-size);
  background-color: var(--bg-accent);
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: filter 300ms;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.nav-button svg,
.icon-right svg {
  fill: var(--text-color);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <img src="logo.png" width="180px" alt="logo" class="nav-logo">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zm-141.651-35.33c4.937-32.999-20.191-50.739-54.55-62.573l11.146-44.702-27.213-6.781-10.851 43.524c-7.154-1.783-14.502-3.464-21.803-5.13l10.929-43.81-27.198-6.781-11.153 44.686c-5.922-1.349-11.735-2.682-17.377-4.084l.031-.14-37.53-9.37-7.239 29.062s20.191 4.627 19.765 4.913c11.022 2.751 13.014 10.044 12.68 15.825l-12.696 50.925c.76.194 1.744.473 2.829.907-.907-.225-1.876-.473-2.876-.713l-17.796 71.338c-1.349 3.348-4.767 8.37-12.471 6.464.271.395-19.78-4.937-19.78-4.937l-13.51 31.147 35.414 8.827c6.588 1.651 13.045 3.379 19.4 5.006l-11.262 45.213 27.182 6.781 11.153-44.733a1038.209 1038.209 0 0 0 21.687 5.627l-11.115 44.523 27.213 6.781 11.262-45.128c46.404 8.781 81.299 5.239 95.986-36.727 11.836-33.79-.589-53.281-25.004-65.991 17.78-4.098 31.174-15.792 34.747-39.949zm-62.177 87.179c-8.41 33.79-65.308 15.523-83.755 10.943l14.944-59.899c18.446 4.603 77.6 13.717 68.811 48.956zm8.417-87.667c-7.673 30.736-55.031 15.12-70.393 11.292l13.548-54.327c15.363 3.828 64.836 10.973 56.845 43.035z"></path></svg>Administrativo</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M425.09 65.83c-39.88 0-73.28 25.73-83.66 64.33-18.16-58.06-65.5-64.33-84.95-64.33-19.78 0-66.8 6.28-85.28 64.33-10.38-38.6-43.45-64.33-83.66-64.33C38.59 65.83 0 99.72 0 143.03c0 28.96 4.18 33.27 77.17 233.48 22.37 60.57 67.77 69.35 92.74 69.35 39.23 0 70.04-19.46 85.93-53.98 15.89 34.83 46.69 54.29 85.93 54.29 24.97 0 70.36-9.1 92.74-69.67 76.55-208.65 77.5-205.58 77.5-227.2.63-48.32-36.01-83.47-86.92-83.47zm26.34 114.81l-65.57 176.44c-7.92 21.49-21.22 37.22-46.24 37.22-23.44 0-37.38-12.41-44.03-33.9l-39.28-117.42h-.95L216.08 360.4c-6.96 21.5-20.9 33.6-44.02 33.6-25.02 0-38.33-15.74-46.24-37.22L60.88 181.55c-5.38-14.83-7.92-23.91-7.92-34.5 0-16.34 15.84-29.36 38.33-29.36 18.69 0 31.99 11.8 36.11 29.05l44.03 139.82h.95l44.66-136.79c6.02-19.67 16.47-32.08 38.96-32.08s32.94 12.11 38.96 32.08l44.66 136.79h.95l44.03-139.82c4.12-17.25 17.42-29.05 36.11-29.05 22.17 0 38.33 13.32 38.33 35.71-.32 7.87-4.12 16.04-7.61 27.24z"></path></svg>Financeiro</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-button"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M425.09 65.83c-39.88 0-73.28 25.73-83.66 64.33-18.16-58.06-65.5-64.33-84.95-64.33-19.78 0-66.8 6.28-85.28 64.33-10.38-38.6-43.45-64.33-83.66-64.33C38.59 65.83 0 99.72 0 143.03c0 28.96 4.18 33.27 77.17 233.48 22.37 60.57 67.77 69.35 92.74 69.35 39.23 0 70.04-19.46 85.93-53.98 15.89 34.83 46.69 54.29 85.93 54.29 24.97 0 70.36-9.1 92.74-69.67 76.55-208.65 77.5-205.58 77.5-227.2.63-48.32-36.01-83.47-86.92-83.47zm26.34 114.81l-65.57 176.44c-7.92 21.49-21.22 37.22-46.24 37.22-23.44 0-37.38-12.41-44.03-33.9l-39.28-117.42h-.95L216.08 360.4c-6.96 21.5-20.9 33.6-44.02 33.6-25.02 0-38.33-15.74-46.24-37.22L60.88 181.55c-5.38-14.83-7.92-23.91-7.92-34.5 0-16.34 15.84-29.36 38.33-29.36 18.69 0 31.99 11.8 36.11 29.05l44.03 139.82h.95l44.66-136.79c6.02-19.67 16.47-32.08 38.96-32.08s32.94 12.11 38.96 32.08l44.66 136.79h.95l44.03-139.82c4.12-17.25 17.42-29.05 36.11-29.05 22.17 0 38.33 13.32 38.33 35.71-.32 7.87-4.12 16.04-7.61 27.24z"></path></svg>TI</a></li>  </ul>
</div>
```